# Решить пример на assembler tasm

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Нужна помощь в решении примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как осуществить на ассемблере ввод двух чисел (десятичных) с клавиатуры и последующий их вывод (пример кода пожалуйста), перепробовал множество вариантов, ничего не получилось

```
DATA SEGMENT
    sin db 'Enter number: $'
    buf label byte
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
        ASSUME cs:code, ds:DATA

start:
       lea dx, sin
       mov ah, 9
       int 21h
       lea dx,buf
       mov ah,0ah
       int 21h
       // решение примера
       mov ah, 9
       int 21h
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: ну вы почитайте справочник, то про аргументы для функции 0ah, и вводить надо в массив байт, а не в один

Comment: @PavelGridin, можешь написать пример как это сделать

Comment: могу, но вы для чего учитесь? в справочник трудно посмотреть?

Comment: @PavelGridin, я же написал, что перепробовал много вариантов и ни чего не получилось, если бы я мог посмотреть в справочнике и сделать сам, то я бы сюда не написал

Comment: @MaNa, вы попробовали много вариантов, но вставили в вопрос код который ничего не делает по сути. Код в вопросе должен демонстрировать проблему, иначе в нем нет смысла. Почитайте вот это: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: По вопросу: [Ввод чисел с консоли](http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/023-vvod-chisel-s-konsoli/), [Вывод чисел на консоль](http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/). Диалект ассемблера по ссылкам fasm, но разобраться можно.

Answer (score 2):

Для корректной работы функции 0ah необходимо подготовить буфер - указав на него DS:DX:
- первый байт MAX - содержит максимальную длину предполагаемого ввода;
- второй байт резервируем для счетчика введенных символов без завершающего CR;
- резервируем количество байт указанных в MAX - тут будут полученные символы в кодах ASCII;
- резервируем для символа CR.

Определяйтесь с размерностью числа - так понимаю, вам ведь не цифру надо, а число.
Выделяйте под буфер размер необходимое число байт, из расчета: MAX + LENGTH + количество знаков числа + CR. Не забудем выделить место для чисел.

```
buf          db 4
buf__len     db ?
buf__string  db 5 dup (?) 
num1         dw ?
num2         dw ?
```

Ввод по функции 0ah будет осуществляться до нажатия 'Enter' - символа CR(0dh). Введенная строка начнется с третьего байта в буфере DS:DX, до 0dh (конец строки) Проверяем валидность значений (каждый байт в диапазоне от 30h до 39h), преобразуем в число и сохраняем. Повторяем ввод - лучше написать для этого процедуру.

Полученные числа преобразуем в символьную строку, объединяем с $ на хвосте, указываем на строку DS:DX и через функцию 09h отправляем на экран.

Сори, код писать негде - поэтому только сухая последовательность. Честно говоря, думал что это уже нигде не проходят.

P.S. немного кода поможет)
Так вот можно проверить что выбранный символ число:

```
cmp al,30h  ;если меньше чем 0 в кодировке ASCII
jc error
cmp al,39h  ;если больше чем 9 в кодировке ASCII
ja error
```

Вот вариант ввода числа на основе функции 01h(без буфера). В CX собирает десятичное число в шестнадцатеричном представлении:

```
;десятичный множитель
    mov bx,10

start_input:   
;получим первый символ
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h

;если не цифра, то повторим ввод
    cmp al,30h
    jc start_input
    cmp al,39h
    ja start_input

;преобразуем в числовое значение
    sub al,30h
    mov cx,ax

loop:
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    cmp al,0dh
    je exit

;если не цифра, то повторим ввод
    cmp al,30h
    jc loop
    cmp al,39h
    ja loop

;преобразуем в числовое значение
    sub al,30h
    cbw
    xchg ax,cx

;предыдущие значения умножим на 10
    mul bx
    add cx,ax
    jmp loop
exit:
```